# Browserify for production, and something else for development

Tags: javascript, browserify

Browserify great and all, and makes it really sweet (even compared to require.js), but the idea of bundling everything into one minified file although sounds great for final version of the app, feels like something I would like to avoid during development. Wouldn't it make difficult to debug stuff?

Is it possible to use browserify and still keep all javascript files and make it more transparent for the browser during development? And when you ready to ship it run browserify bundler and minify everything into one file?

Or maybe there's better approach - like keeping all scripts listed in a partial that gets included to the main page for development or something like that?

Upd: I just found that there's an option:

```
--debug -d  Enable source maps that allow you to debug your files separately.
```

Is that helpful? I guess it is. But I suppose it still makes it difficult if want to use coffeescript source maps

Comment: `--debug` works well with CoffeeScript source maps. Please try and report back your experience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you shouldn't use minified/concatenated Javascript in development. Luckly there are a myriad of ways of solving this particular issue, I recommend taking a look into an automated build process like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the question thoroughly. In particular I'm asking about Browserify (http://browserify.org). It's almost like: -"How can I cook pizza without burning it?" -"Hey, pizza bad for your health and burned pizza is definitely the worst, I suggest you better exercise and eat celery"

Comment: Grunt is a task runner. Make a task that runs Browserify. Did you read the page throughly? https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify

Comment: As for the analogy I believe this is more along the line of "How can I cook a pizza without burning it?" - "Don't throw it directly into the fire, use an oven".

Comment: You know what.. I stand corrected. Although I'm already using `grunt-browserify` I just realized that never bothered to read its read.me carefully. It actually explains a lot and suggest best practices. Thank you

Comment: This answer should include an actual answer in it..  this isn't doing the SO community any favors. Comments are great and all.. but you should update your answer.